# 「見出し」と「水平線」の Markdown の説明で、要素名の書かれ方が不自然

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

### 不具合事象

[Markdown 編集ヘルプ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) では、「見出し」と「水平線」の Markdown の書式について、以下のように説明があります。それぞれの書式の説明文の冒頭に、 Markdown で使用される要素が書かれていますが、それぞれ「`<h1><h2>` 最上位」や「`<hr/>` ハイフン」などのように読めるため、要素名の挿入される位置に不自然さを感じます。

> ### 見出し <sup>[[1]](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)</sup>
>
> `<h1><h2>` 最上位とその次のレベルの見出しには、テキストに下線を 引きます:
>
> ---
>
> ### 水平線
>
> `<hr/>` ハイフン、アスタリスク、または下線を 1 行に 3 個以上並べることで水平線 を挿入できます:

---

### 改善案

[原文](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) を読む限りでは、それぞれの要素名は以下のような位置に挿入されるほうが良いのではないかと思います。

> ### 見出し
>
> 最上位とその次のレベルの見出し `<h1>` `<h2>` を作成するには、テキストに下線を引きます:
>
> ---
>
> ### 水平線
>
> ハイフン、アスタリスク、または下線を 1 行に 3 個以上並べることで水平線 `<hr/>` を挿入できます:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

変更が完了いたしました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
見出しのストリングはこちらです -> https://ja.traducir.win/string/3638

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
水平線のストリングはこちらです -> https://ja.traducir.win/string/7389

Comment: Markdown ヘルプはヘルプページの一部という印象だったので、 traducir.win の確認をしていませんでした。ご対応ありがとうございます。

Comment: @supa こちらこそ改善案どうもありがとうございました！ヘルプページはモデレータさんが編集可能な箇所とTraducir.winで訳す箇所があり少し分かりづらいですよね。ですのでこのように一旦メタでご指摘いただくと大変嬉しいです。